# Supremum and Infimum of a Bounded subset of R.

Tags: real-analysis

I started to study the concepts of supremum and infimum of sets of real numbers. I am trying to prove the following:

Let A be a nonempty bounded subset of R and let r in R such that x-y is less than r for all x,y in A. Prove that sup(A)-inf(A) is at most r.

Any hint/help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you forget to finish writing the question? What is $x-y$, and how does it relate to $A$ or $r$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Don't know why the question wasn't correctly posted... I already edited it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** For each $\epsilon >0$ pick some $x>\sup(A)-\epsilon, y<\inf(A)+\epsilon$ and show that 
$$r \leq \sup(A)-\inf(A)+2 \epsilon$$